# Supporting SNI in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking, sni

I have a root certificate that is used to sign with different sub-domain names on the server which is basically implementation of SNI in backend. Now How can I use that certificate and sub-domain name to validate the request.

Answer (score 2):

SNI is supported out of the box. And from my experience it works (two second-level domains on single IP)

I see 3 reasons if it doesn't work for you:

1. Your backend is not configured properly. You can check if the server returns an expected certificate with Safari.
2. Your certificate is self-signed. In this case you should check AFSecurityPolicy for pinned certificates, there's nothing special with SNI.
3. Your certificate is not valid for sub-domains. This also could be checked with AFSecurityPolicy.

Comment: I have confirmed my backend is configured properly, as same certificate with host name is working on Android Webservice call. certificate is valid for domain name and for validating sub-domain we have define host name.  Also pinned the certificate correctly. you have any idea how it can be achieved in iOS.

Comment: If you're use a certificate pinning, I would start with breakpoint in AFSecurityPolicy.evaluateServerTrust where you can check many aspects of the connection establishing: if the certificate checking started at all; which certificate received by the client; which step of the method returns NO.

And by the way, which the error you're getting currently?

Comment: Also evaluateServerTrust return NO, this line of code return NO, if (!AFServerTrustIsValid(serverTrust) && !self.allowInvalidCertificates) {
        return NO;
    } let me know if you have any idea why its returning NO.

Comment: @WildFire so your case is #3 - like a domain is example1.com and certificate is valid for *.example2.com?

In this case it's obvious that you should set allowInvalidCertificates to YES, to ignore domain's validation. Then your app will rely on pinned certificate - just add it in DER format into the project with ".cer" extension, it will be consumed automagically inside -defaultPinnedCertificates.

Suitable file could be obtained by this command:
`openssl s_client -servername api.example.org -connect api.example.org:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform DER > ~/api.example.org.cer`

Comment: I have done everything as you have described but it still not working, Basically i have root certificate for domain example.com and API is hosted on sub-domain domainname.example.com. Basically we have different sub-domains for the same base name. we want to use the same root certificate for all the sub-domains by using support of SNI.

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/dstd/CertExample - the example working with self-signed certificate with non-valid domain name (it also was tested with our SNI-enabled server). It uses AFSSLPinningModePublicKey mode if the certificate is not valid for the domain.

If it still not working, try to set a breakpoint to `NSArray *publicKeys = AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust(serverTrust);` in `-evaluateServerTrust:` and check length of this chain. All certificates of the chain should be included into your project and their public keys are visible in `pinnedPublicKeys` property in debugger.

Comment: Certificate you are using in sample code is same on server as well on client. That's why its working. If i put my root certificate and do all the things it still fails in for (id trustChainPublicKey in publicKeys) {
                for (id pinnedPublicKey in self.pinnedPublicKeys) {
                    if (AFSecKeyIsEqualToKey((__bridge SecKeyRef)trustChainPublicKey, (__bridge SecKeyRef)pinnedPublicKey)) {
                        trustedPublicKeyCount += 1;
                    }
                }
            } in matching the key.